# Error "Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app and I get the error

> Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'

I get this error in ViewController.h.

Here is the code I'm using when I get the error:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
- (IBAction)Contact:(id)sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please paste more code. Sometimes the errors are somewhere else. Check that you have @interface and @end and do a clean before compiling.